# Server resolves to correct IP when using FQDN but incorrectly when using shortname

Tags: domain-name-system, netbios, wins, resolution

Win2k3 environment using WINs

server resolves to the correct IP when I use the FQDN, but resolves to a different IP when I use the shortname.

I've tried resetting NetBios cache and purging/reloading remote cache table (nbtstat), but that doesn't work.

Any other ideas on how I can get the server to resolve to the same IP when using both shortname and FQDN?

Comment: What tool are you using to do these lookups?

Comment: What is your primary dns suffix?  You can see this with an: ipconfig /all from a cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Snortname resolution follows a couple of different paths, both DNS and NetBIOS. Since purging the NBT cache isn't working for you, it must be getting it from somewhere else like WINS. When attempting to resolve a shortname by DNS, it will try resolving each of the domains listed in the DNS search list in order until it finds it. If it finds the wrong one first, it will return that.

If you have a split DNS where servers have both an AD name and a static DNS name, such as, `servname.addom.example.com` and `servname.servers.example.com`, and have the `servers.example.com` domain listed in your search list before `addom.example.com`, then it will be the servers.example.com version of that name that will be returned. It is for this reason that I recommend to our own people to ensure that AD's DNS domain tops all such search lists.

Comment: You're comment sent me in the right direction. AD servers had residual entries for the old IP. deleting those from the domain controllers resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if there is an entry for it in the [Lmhosts](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/l/lmhost.htm) file? If so then it will use that IP address instead of looking up the IP using WINS or NetBIOS.

Comment: Yes. There are entries in there, but none that point to that name or IP.